# JSF rich:pickList add drag and drop?

Tags: java, jsf, drag-and-drop, richfaces

I have task to make two multiple selections with drag and drop.

I used the rich:pickList from [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList) example, customized it. Now I want to not just controling items with buttons, but also drag and drop feature. Found [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dragDrop&skin=blueSky) example.

How it can be used together? And I must implement multiple drag and drop not just one element, but all selected items.

Can it done by rich faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We switched to [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/). It has much more components and [picklist](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf) with drag&drop.